# function on nested ranked lists: comparing lists of data against combinations of another list with data R

Tags: r

I really need help with my script, I am not a professional in R.

Some background information about what I want to do.

There are two ranked lists of data ( drugs,diseases ). In these datasets there is information about how genes change in expression.

The drugRL(drug) dataset is a dataset which is a ranked list. The diseaseRL(disease) dataset is a dataset which in the description says it is the same ( ?diseaseRL ), but seems not to be a ranked list.

What i did was i took the absolute numbers from the diseaseRL dataset and normalized the data using the range of the data ( max - min of a vector of a particular disease in that dataset ).

So what i have now are two lists of dataframes containing the information of gene expression, as ranked lists.

Some code examples, first build the needed packages:

```
# Compile/install packages using biocLite.
#source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
#biocLite("DrugVsDiseasedata")
#biocLite("gespeR")
#biocLite("DrugVsDisease") # may not be needed.
```

Then import packages/datasets :

```
#import libraries
library("DrugVsDisease")#may not be needed
library("DrugVsDiseasedata")
library("cMap2data")
library("gespeR")

#import datasets
data(diseaseRL)
data(drugRL)


> class(drugRL)
[1] "matrix"
> 

> class(diseaseRL)
[1] "matrix"
> 


> str(drugRL)
 num [1:11709, 1:1309] 1870 4059 2250 10284 8999 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11709] "ZNF702P" "SAMD4A" "VN1R1" "ZNF419" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:1309] "(+)-chelidonine" "(+)-isoprenaline" "(+/-)-catechin" "(-)-MK-801" ...
> 

> str(diseaseRL)
 num [1:11709, 1:45] 0.01683 -0.00112 -0.00126 0.04902 0.02605 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11709] "LINC00115" "GOT2P1" "TP73-AS1" "PIN1P1" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:45] "wilms-tumor" "glaucoma-open-angle" "diabetes-mellitus-type-ii" "soft-tissue-sarcoma" ...
>
```

Now comes the part where i created a function to normalize the datasets:

```
NormalizeRLData <- function(x){

data.rankedlist <- x
data.rankedlist.abs <- as.data.frame(abs(data.rankedlist))
data.rankedlist.abs.ordered <- 
data.rankedlist.abs[order(data.rankedlist.abs,decreasing=T), , drop = FALSE]

data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.max <- max(data.rankedlist.abs.ordered)
data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.min <- min(data.rankedlist.abs.ordered)

data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.normalizedToOwnRange <- (data.rankedlist.abs.ordered 
/ 
(data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.max - data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.min ))

data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.normalizedToOwnRange.ordered <- 
data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.normalizedToOwnRange[order(
data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.normalizedToOwnRange,decreasing=T ), , drop = 
FALSE]

return(data.rankedlist.abs.ordered.normalizedToOwnRange.ordered)
}

diseaseRL.normalized <- apply(diseaseRL,2,NormalizeRLData)
drugRL.normalized <- apply(drugRL,2,NormalizeRLData)
```

There are multiple doubts/problems i have in order to proceed. I am unsure if what i did till now can be done more effectively, in particular in regards to the following, using rank-biased overlap (RBO).

RBO is a function which is able to compare two ranked lists. I want to make use of this function for the lists of normalized data, containing data.frames of the genes (for the disease and drug ranked lists). The input of this rbo function is a named vector.

example :

```
> a <- c(4,2,5,5)
> b <- c(1,2,3,4)
> names(a) <- c('one','two','three','four')
> names(b) <- c('one','two','three','four')
> rbo(a,b, p = 0.95)
[1] 0.9650417
```

What is the most efficient way to do this, so first of all can i have a better output then what i have at the moment to provide to the rbo function ?

And second :

If not ( or similar case ), I will have a list of data.frames containing the gene information for ether a drug, and another for a disease. I want to do the rbo function for every drug against every disease.

I tried using sapply, but i could not get it to work properly, and I am unsure if it is the right way to go. I need to maintain the names of the drugs , and for the other dataset the name of the disease, but also the gene names are important. So i can later check with genes and disease and drugs are having interactions.

I really hope someone here can shed some light into this !

p.s: If any one tries to help me here, but has problem compiling the packages, I may help ! Maybe i could send an example dataset ( not sure if i can attach anything here directly ).

Best Regards,
Rick

Answer (score 0):

First, your user-defined method can vastly be reduced in verbosity. No need to cast into `data.frame`, initially `order`, or use *drop* in `[]` as vectors are being passed into the method. Consider the following adjustment where last line is the returned object:

```
NormalizeRLData <- function(x){
  rnklist <- abs(x)
  rnklist <- rnklist[order(rnklist)]

  normRng <- rnklist / (max(rnklist) - min(rnklist))
  normRng[order(normRng, decreasing = TRUE)]
}


diseaseRL.normalized <- apply(diseaseRL,2,NormalizeRLData)
drugRL.normalized <- apply(drugRL,2,NormalizeRLData)
```

Secondly, your normalized matrices (not dataframes) can possibly indeed be run with `sapply` by passing two inputs into the method, specifically both number of columns of each matrix as arguments. When two vectors are passed in `sapply` a cartesian product is applied where all combinations between both sets are iterated.

Since matrices maintain named columns and rows, it should adhere to `rbo` requirements. The return will be a matrix M x N where dimensions are the number of columns of *disease* and *drug* matrices.

```
# TWO-INPUT SAPPLY
rbo_mat <- sapply(seq(ncol(diseaseRL.normalized)), function(i,j) rbo(diseaseRL.normalized[,i], drugRL.normalized[,j], p = 0.95), 
                  seq(ncol(drugRL.normalized)))

# EQUIVALENT WITH VAPPLY TO [V]ERIFY TYPE AND LENGTH OF OUTPUT
rbo_mat <- vapply(seq(ncol(diseaseRL.normalized)), function(i,j) rbo(diseaseRL.normalized[,i], drugRL.normalized[,j], p = 0.95), 
                  numeric(seq(ncol(drugRL.normalized))),
                  seq(ncol(drugRL.normalized)))
```

You might even be able to use the lesser know *apply* function, `rapply` (recursive apply):

```
cols_list <- list(seq(ncol(diseaseRL.normalized)), seq(ncol(drugRL.normalized)))

rbo_mat2 <- rapply(cols_list, function(i,j) rbo(drugRL.normalized[,j], diseaseRL.normalized[,i], p = 0.95), 
                   how="replace")[[1]]
```

---

**TEST EXAMPLE**

Because I cannot reproduce OP's data and do not have necessary packages, below is working example of above methodology with random normal data and uses the correlation function, `cor` as substitute for `rbo`:

```
set.seed(142)

mat1 <- sapply(1:10, function(i) rnorm(20))
colnames(mat1) <-  LETTERS[1:10]
rownames(mat1) <- letters[1:20]

str(mat1)
#  num [1:20, 1:10] 1.255 1.704 0.88 -0.582 -0.169 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:20] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#   ..$ : chr [1:10] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

mat2 <- sapply(1:5, function(i) rnorm(20))
colnames(mat2) <-  LETTERS[1:5]
rownames(mat2) <- letters[1:20]

str(mat2)    
#  num [1:20, 1:5] -0.156 0.449 -0.822 -1.062 0.838 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:20] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#   ..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

corr_mat <- sapply(seq(ncol(mat1)), function(i,j) cor(mat1[,i], mat2[,j]), 
                   seq(ncol(mat2)))

corr_mat2 <- vapply(seq(ncol(mat1)), function(i,j) cor(mat1[,i], mat2[,j]), 
                    numeric(ncol(mat2)),
                    seq(ncol(mat2)))

corr_mat3 <- rapply(list(seq(ncol(mat1)), ncol(mat2)), function(i,j) cor(mat2[,j], mat1[,i]), 
                    how="replace")[[1]]
```